# Why is Forge queue using the deprecated queue:listen command?

Tags: laravel, beanstalkd, forge, envoyer.io

## Background

We have historically had trouble with deploying during operational hours (our setup: we have two EC2 instances behind a load balancer, which each instance having it's own beanstalkd queue. Each instance is configured using forge, and we autodeploy both using Envoyer.

Our Envoyer has a post deployment script that is supposed to automatically restart the queues after each deploy so that the jobs inside the queues can update to pick up on the latest code changes:

```
cd {{release}}

echo "" | sudo -S service php7.1-fpm reload

if [ -f artisan ]
then
    php artisan config:cache
    php artisan queue:restart
fi
```

The problem is that in random times weirdness happens in the system when we deploy during our operation hours. Ie people using our mobile apps would suddenly stop receiving push notifications (which are Laravel jobs processed by our queues) and other weirdness.

The work around was to restart the queues manually using the Forge queue UI panel. But this fix usually took some time to work, ie sometimes things started going back to normal 40 minutes after we manually restart the queues!

## Analysis

I ran this experiment where I
1. ran an Envoyer deploy which executed the queue restart script, and observed the logs
2. manually restarted queues on forge, then observed the logs

### Logs before Envoyer deploy:

```
forge    11556  0.0  0.0   4504   700 ?        S    05:43   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='low' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=9 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge    11557  3.0  1.2 384800 49476 ?        S    05:43   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=low --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=9 --tries=3 --env=production
forge    11570  0.0  0.0   4504   704 ?        S    05:43   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='default' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=6 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge    11571  3.6  1.2 384800 49496 ?        S    05:43   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=default --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=6 --tries=3 --env=production
forge    11575  0.0  0.0   4504   848 ?        S    05:43   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='high' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=2 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge    11576  5.5  1.2 384800 49764 ?        S    05:43   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=high --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=2 --tries=3 --env=production
forge    11580  0.0  0.0   4504   848 ?        S    05:43   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='marketing' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge    11581 12.0  1.2 384800 49448 ?        S    05:43   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=marketing --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --env=production
forge    11586  0.0  0.0  12920   944 pts/1    S+   05:43   0:00 grep --color=auto artisan
forge    20447  0.0  1.1 374208 46364 ?        S    Mar15   0:36 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=9 --quiet --tries=3 --queue=low
forge    20633  0.1  1.1 374208 46604 ?        S    Mar15   1:52 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=2 --quiet --tries=3 --queue=high
forge    20667  0.0  1.1 374208 46468 ?        S    Mar15   1:00 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=3 --quiet --timeout=60 --tries=3 --queue=marketing
forge    20735  0.0  1.1 374208 46280 ?        S    Mar15   0:44 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=6 --quiet --tries=3 --queue=default
```

### Logs after Envoyer deploy, before manual queue restart:

```
forge    14367  0.0  0.0   4504   696 ?        S    05:49   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='default' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=6 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge    14368  2.0  1.2 384800 49900 ?        S    05:49   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=default --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=6 --tries=3 --env=production
forge    14387  0.0  0.0   4504   784 ?        S    05:49   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='marketing' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge    14388  5.5  1.2 384800 49528 ?        S    05:49   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=marketing --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --env=production
forge    14392  0.0  0.0   4504   692 ?        S    05:49   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='low' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=9 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge    14393 11.0  1.2 384800 49680 ?        S    05:49   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=low --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=9 --tries=3 --env=production
forge    14397  0.0  0.0   4504   696 ?        S    05:49   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='high' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=2 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge    14398 12.0  1.2 384800 49504 ?        S    05:49   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=high --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=2 --tries=3 --env=production
forge    14403  0.0  0.0  12920   964 pts/1    S+   05:49   0:00 grep --color=auto artisan
forge    20447  0.0  1.1 374208 46364 ?        S    Mar15   0:36 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=9 --quiet --tries=3 --queue=low
forge    20633  0.1  1.1 374208 46604 ?        S    Mar15   1:52 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=2 --quiet --tries=3 --queue=high
forge    20667  0.0  1.1 374208 46468 ?        S    Mar15   1:00 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=3 --quiet --timeout=60 --tries=3 --queue=marketing
forge    20735  0.0  1.1 374208 46280 ?        S    Mar15   0:44 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=6 --quiet --tries=3 --queue=default
```

## Logs after Forge manual restart

```
forge    15012  0.6  1.1 374208 46652 ?        S    05:50   0:00 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=3 --quiet --timeout=60 --tries=3 --queue=marketing
forge    15097  0.7  1.1 374208 46368 ?        S    05:50   0:00 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=6 --quiet --tries=3 --queue=default
forge    15144  0.7  1.1 374208 46484 ?        S    05:50   0:00 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=2 --quiet --tries=3 --queue=high
forge    15269  1.1  1.1 374208 46452 ?        S    05:50   0:00 php /home/forge/default/envoyer/current/artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --sleep=9 --quiet --tries=3 --queue=low
forge    15319  0.0  0.0   4504   744 ?        S    05:50   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='default' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=6 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge    15320  4.0  1.2 384800 49716 ?        S    05:50   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=default --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=6 --tries=3 --env=production
forge    15324  0.0  0.0   4504   776 ?        S    05:50   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='high' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=2 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge    15325 12.0  1.2 384800 49496 ?        S    05:50   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=high --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=2 --tries=3 --env=production
forge    15326  0.0  0.0   4504   700 ?        S    05:50   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='low' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=9 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge    15327 12.0  1.2 384800 49716 ?        S    05:50   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=low --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=9 --tries=3 --env=production
forge    15334  0.0  0.0   4504   692 ?        S    05:50   0:00 sh -c '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' queue:work 'beanstalkd' --once --queue='marketing' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --env='production'
forge    15335  0.0  1.2 384800 49864 ?        S    05:50   0:00 /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan queue:work beanstalkd --once --queue=marketing --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --env=production
forge    15340  0.0  0.0  12920  1016 pts/1    S+   05:50   0:00 grep --color=auto artisan
```

Conclusion: all the queue:work commands restart by the Envoyer php `artisan queue:restart` command. However, the `artisan queue:listen` commands are only restarted when we restart supervisor (ie via Forge ui manually).

## Question

Why is Forge still using `queue:listen` although it's deprecated? How does the above explain how the auto-queue (queue:work) restart script isn't good enough, but restarting the supervisor/queue:listen does the job?

Comment: Hi abbood. As you'll see from the edit log, writing posts stylishly in all-lower-case generates a lot of repair work. Your English is clearly excellent, so could I ask you to usual case rules? Over 226 questions, 20-30 readability errors for each one is going to mount up quickly.

Comment: ok @halfer i'll keep that in mind thanks

Comment: hey @MattHumphrey, we eventually moved away from forge all together. It is only good enough for very basic services and didn't scale too well. Sorry about that :(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its old and doesnt have any answers